# Memory leaks when reading and transforming a file into a two-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, malloc, fopen, glibc

I am writing a function in C to load a file as a double dimensional array (`char **`), the problem is that according to Valgrind I have memory leaks, can you help me?

I provide you with a complete example that can be reproduced. Also, my school only allows me certain functions to perform this task: `open`, `fopen`, `close`, `fclose`, `malloc`, `free`, `getline`, `lseek`... (I am not allowed to use `stat`).

I can use my own implementation of `realloc` too.

My code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_free_word_array(char **word_array)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    if (!word_array) {
        return;
    }
    while (word_array[i] != NULL) {
        free(word_array[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    free(word_array);
}

char **append_word_array(char **array, char *line)
{
    size_t array_len = 0;
    while (array[array_len])
        array_len++;
    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (line[len - 1] == '\n')
        line[len - 1] = '\0';
    char **new_array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (array_len + 2));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_len; i++)
        new_array[i] = array[i];
    new_array[array_len] = strdup(line);
    new_array[array_len + 1] = NULL;
    free(array);
    return new_array;
}

char **fill_from_file(char **array, FILE *file)
{
    char *line_buff = NULL;
    size_t line_buff_size = 0;
    ssize_t line_size = getline(&line_buff, &line_buff_size, file);
    while (line_size >= 0) {
        array = append_word_array(array, line_buff);
        free(line_buff);
        line_buff = NULL;
        line_size = getline(&line_buff, &line_buff_size, file);
    }
    free(line_buff);
    return array;
}

char **my_load_file_to_line_array(const char *filepath)
{
    char **word_array = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (!file)
        return NULL;
    word_array = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    if (!word_array)
        return NULL;
    word_array[0] = NULL;
    word_array = fill_from_file(word_array, file);
    fclose(file);
    return word_array;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1; 
    char **array = my_load_file_to_line_array(argv[1]);
    my_free_word_array(array);
    return 0;
}
```

My input test file :

```
 |A B C D E F G H
-+---------------
1|. . . . . . . .
2|. . . . . . . .
3|. . . . . . . .
4|. . . . . . . .
5|. . . . . . . .
6|. . . . . . . .
7|. . . . . . . .
8|. . . . . . . .
```

Valgrind's report:

```
❯ valgrind --leak-check=full ./navy coord.txt
==99157== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==99157== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==99157== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==99157== Command: ./navy coord.txt
==99157== 
==99157== 
==99157== HEAP SUMMARY:
==99157==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 5 blocks
==99157==   total heap usage: 84 allocs, 79 frees, 18,512 bytes allocated
==99157== 
==99157== 72 (40 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==99157==    at 0x4842888: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==99157==    by 0x10980F: append_word_array (my_load_file_to_line_array.c:18)
==99157==    by 0x109914: fill_from_file (my_load_file_to_line_array.c:33)
==99157==    by 0x1099F0: my_load_file_to_line_array (my_load_file_to_line_array.c:62)
==99157==    by 0x1092A5: main (navy.c:17)
==99157== 
==99157== LEAK SUMMARY:
==99157==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==99157==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 4 blocks
==99157==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==99157==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==99157==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==99157== 
==99157== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==99157== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: "I provide you with a complete example that can be reproduced." hmmm.... `main` ?

Comment: *"I provide you with a complete example that can be reproduced."* ---> Can't reproduce.

Comment: There's a typo in ```main()```. `lod...` ---> `load...`

Comment: `size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (line[len - 1] == '\n')
        line[len - 1] = '\0';` will break if line is `""`.

Comment: I downloaded and ran your program with some simple input using `valgrind`. It reported _no_ leaks. What is the [minimal] input you're using that causes an issue? Please edit your question and post the sample input in a separate code block.

Comment: Any reason why you ignore the value of `malloc()` in the `append()` function? You do not ignore it anywhere else.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `realloc`?

Comment: I also compiled and run your program. There are no leaks. Could be you are testing an older version.

Comment: Is the input file minimal? What happens if you remove lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems:

- you should reset `line_buff_size` to `0` after `line_buff = NULL;` in `fill_from_file`.  Or better: keep the `line_buff` buffer growing as you iterate in the loop and only free it after the end of the loop.
- you should pass the current array length to `append_word_array` to avoid scanning for the NULL terminator.
- testing `if (line[len - 1] == '\n')` has undefined behavior if `line` has a length of `0`, which is possible if the file contains embedded null bytes.
- in case of allocation error for the initial call to `malloc()`, you return `NULL` omitting the `fclose(file)`.
- if `realloc` is allowed, you could use it with caution in `append_word_array`.

These issues are unlikely to have caused the reported memory leaks. There is a chance the problem is not related to your code (or to this version of the code). You should try and reduce the test file length and post the smallest input that still produces a leak summary with valgrind?

You can also try this modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_free_word_array(char **word_array)
{
    if (word_array) {
        size_t i = 0;
        while (word_array[i] != NULL) {
            free(word_array[i]);
            ++i;
        }
        free(word_array);
    }
}

char **append_word_array(char **array, size_t *array_len, const char *line)
{
    char *copy = strdup(line);
    char **new_array = realloc(array, sizeof(*array) * (*array_len + 2));
    if (copy == NULL || new_array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation error");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_array[*array_len] = copy;
    new_array[*array_len + 1] = NULL;
    *array_len += 1;
    return new_array;
}

char **fill_from_file(FILE *file)
{
    char **array = NULL;
    size_t array_len = 0;
    char *line_buff = NULL;
    size_t line_buff_size = 0;
    ssize_t line_length;
    while ((line_size = getline(&line_buff, &line_buff_size, file)) >= 0) {
        if (line_length > 0 && line_buff[line_length - 1] == '\n')
            line_buff[line_length - 1] = '\0';
        array = append_word_array(array, &array_len, line_buff);
    }
    free(line_buff);
    return array;
}

char **my_load_file_to_line_array(const char *filepath)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (!file)
        return NULL;
    char **word_array = fill_from_file(file);
    fclose(file);
    return word_array;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1; 
    char **array = my_load_file_to_line_array(argv[1]);
    my_free_word_array(array);
    return 0;
}
```